# じゃor じゃあ for meaning "well then"

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

Both of these translate to "well then", for example, both would be valid:

> じゃ、またね！

*Well then, bye!*

> じゃあ、パンをください。

*Well then, the bread, please.*

They are both more casual than でわ for example:

> でわ、さよんなら。

*Well then, goodbye.*

But which is more commonly used? Are there any nuances between them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`でわ` is an incorrect form (it's written `では` instead).

In terms of nuance, `じゃ` or `じゃあ` are very colloquial (whereas `では` is not).

`じゃ` is a bit more "light" IMO. As in, it can just be a filler. For example, `じゃ、バイバイ！` just means "Right, bye!".

`じゃあ` means it has real semantic meaning - for example, `じゃあ、バイバイ！` means "In that case, bye!". For example it can express annoyance (`え、持ってきてくれなかったの？じゃあバイバイ！`), or emphasize you are doing something *because of* something (`え、いらないの？じゃあ、もう一つ食べようかな (otherwise I wouldn't have)`).

They are really close in meaning though (e.g. it'd be the same meaning if you said `え、持ってきてくれなかったの？じゃバイバイ！` or `え、いらないの？じゃ、もう一つ食べようかな`).

では is more formal (e.g. `では、授業を始めます`, `では、さようなら`), and it would be odd to use it in a colloquial way (for example, it's slightly odd to say `では、バイバイ！`). In terms of meaning it's closer to `じゃ` (as opposed to `じゃあ`).

All three have very similar meanings though.